# Pushing (Push-)buttons causes exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, raspberry-pi, uwp

today I've got a special problem.
I have a Raspberry Pi running Win10IoT, with a pushbutton connected to GPIO6. In my App, there's an Ellipse, which should be painted red, when the button is pressed.
It worked.. until today! I've added a MediaElement with a simple ComboBox to load some music, but now the pushbutton throws an exception:

> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Excep_FromHResult 0x8001010E)

Another problem: The second page "Mehr Wetter...", in english "more weather" opens a new frame. At the bottom left of this new frame, there's a back button, which should lead you back to the MainPage. But clicking this button also throws an exception: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Because at least the second error doesn't happen under x86, I assumed, it's a hardware problem. I already re-installed Win10IoT on the Pi, but it's still the same and unfortunately I don't have a second Raspberry to test it.

Is there anybody out there, who can help me?

I've uploaded the complete solution [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnAzwO51R3Ve739fvl4Jbznzp2pP)!

Comment: *"Because at least the second error doesn't happen under x86, I assumed, it's a hardware problem."* - Uhm, no. This is a bug in your code, that simply doesn't manifest itself when targeting x86. x86 is **extremely** forgiving when it comes to bugs (like unaligned memory accesses).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, seems I've sold at least the second problem.
It was a problem with opening the GPIO-Pins. When you leave and re-enter the MainPage, the program tries to open the pin *again*.
So, if anyone has the same problem, just dispose the GPIOs before leaving the page.

According to the first problem, it seems, that I can't manipulate elements inside a hub. Maybe it's a problem with the Dispatcher, but I'm on it.